# PHP: How to check if a date is today, yesterday or tomorrow

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I would like to check, if a date is today, tomorrow, yesterday or else.
But my code doesn't work.

Code:

```
$timestamp = "2014.09.02T13:34";
$date = date("d.m.Y H:i");
$match_date = date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime($timestamp));

if($date == $match_date) { 

    //Today

} elseif(strtotime("-1 day", $date) == $match_date) {

    //Yesterday

} elseif(strtotime("+1 day", $date) == $match_date) {

    //Tomorrow

} else {

    //Sometime

}
```

The Code always goes in the else case.

Comment: How is `$timestamp` defined and where?

Comment: check date using strtotime

Comment: I would advice you to take a look at **Datetime** object.. And most likely your $timestamp isn't being converted correctly.

Comment: The $timestamp is Like `"2014.09.02T13:34"`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**First.** You have mistake in using function `strtotime` see [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )
```

You need modify your code to pass integer timestamp into this function.

**Second.** You use format **d.m.Y H:i** that includes time part. If you wish to compare only dates, you must remove time part, e.g. `$date = date("d.m.Y");``

**Third.** I am not sure if it works in the same way for you, but my PHP doesn't understand date format from `$timestamp` and returns **01.01.1970 02:00** into `$match_date`

```
$timestamp = "2014.09.02T13:34";
date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime($timestamp)) === "01.01.1970 02:00";
```

You need to check if `strtotime($timestamp)` returns correct date string. If no, you need to specify format which is used in `$timestamp` variable. You can do this using one of functions [`date_parse_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) or [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

This is a work example:

```
$timestamp = "2014.09.02T13:34";

$today = new DateTime("today"); // This object represents current date/time with time set to midnight

$match_date = DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y.m.d\\TH:i", $timestamp );
$match_date->setTime( 0, 0, 0 ); // set time part to midnight, in order to prevent partial comparison

$diff = $today->diff( $match_date );
$diffDays = (integer)$diff->format( "%R%a" ); // Extract days count in interval

switch( $diffDays ) {
    case 0:
        echo "//Today";
        break;
    case -1:
        echo "//Yesterday";
        break;
    case +1:
        echo "//Tomorrow";
        break;
    default:
        echo "//Sometime";
}
```

Comment: What sort of `case` would lead to the "sometimes" in your `switch`? Only when `$today` or `$match_date` don't properly format as dates, maybe?

Comment: A possible improvement: `$today` can be defined as just `new DateTime("today")`, which means today at midnight -- the time part will be automatically zeroed out.

Comment: Checking `(integer)$diff->format( "%R%a" ) == 0` on its own is inaccurate. It is true for the same day ten years ago too. Check `$diff->days == 0` for today, and `$diff->days == 1` with `$diff->invert` for yesterday / tomorrow.

Answer (score 31):

```
<?php 
 $current = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
 $date    = strtotime("2014-09-05");

 $datediff = $date - $current;
 $difference = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
 if($difference==0)
 {
    echo 'today';
 }
 else if($difference > 1)
 {
    echo 'Future Date';
 }
 else if($difference > 0)
 {
    echo 'tomorrow';
 }
 else if($difference < -1)
 {
    echo 'Long Back';
 }
 else
 {
    echo 'yesterday';
 }  
?>
```

Comment: Every time you see the number 86400 (60 * 60 * 24) in code, you know it has a bug. As is true in this case also: http://ideone.com/2D2N8I

Comment: @Jon : Why this number is considered as a bug?

Comment: @DeepakJain because not all days are 86400 seconds long. There are shorter days and longer days because of daylight savings time, there are leap seconds, all of these are of course rare occurrences but they will break your code when they happen. See for example in the ideone link I gave above how this code reports the wrong result if you pick certain specific dates.

Comment: Thanks @Jon for the explanation! I'll make a note of it as it seems an important point to remember.

Comment: Are you sure this works? if the date belongs to 17 hours ago and let's say it's 4PM , it belongs to yesterday but your code is gonna show Today

Comment: This should not have so many upvotes. This is calculating 24 hour periods, not whether the "date" was truly yesterday. Use this with caution as it may lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 16):

I think this will help you:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$match_date = new DateTime($timestamp);
$interval = $date->diff($match_date);

if($interval->days == 0) {

    //Today

} elseif($interval->days == 1) {
    if($interval->invert == 0) {
        //Yesterday
    } else {
        //Tomorrow
    }
} else {
    //Sometime
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well. Just a warning, it is not always accurate. For example, if the time now is 10:30am and the time yesterday is 10:58am, $interval->days == 0, which makes that date seem to be "Today," which is not true.

Comment: This is not a check for "today", but for "last 24 hrs"

Comment: Today is not difference between dates. Today is the same day.

Answer (score 10):

There is no built-in functions to do that in Php (shame ^^). You want to compare a date string to today, you could use a simple `substr` to achieve it:

```
if (substr($timestamp, 0, 10) === date('Y.m.d')) { today }
elseif (substr($timestamp, 0, 10) === date('Y.m.d', strtotime('-1 day')) { yesterday }
```

No date conversion, simple.

Comment: If you have the integers, why would you compare the strings? :D
Btw which language has such function?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Swift does!

Answer (score 10):

Simple one liners for today/yesterday/tomorrow:

```
$someDate = '2021-11-07'; // date in any format

$isToday = date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', strtotime($someDate));
$isYesterday = date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', strtotime($someDate) + 86400);
$isTomorrow = date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', strtotime($someDate) - 86400);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function getRangeDateString($timestamp) {
    if ($timestamp) {
        $currentTime=strtotime('today');
        // Reset time to 00:00:00
        $timestamp=strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',$timestamp));
        $days=round(($timestamp-$currentTime)/86400);
        switch($days) {
            case '0';
                return 'Today';
                break;
            case '-1';
                return 'Yesterday';
                break;
            case '-2';
                return 'Day before yesterday';
                break;
            case '1';
                return 'Tomorrow';
                break;
            case '2';
                return 'Day after tomorrow';
                break;
            default:
                if ($days > 0) {
                    return 'In '.$days.' days';
                } else {
                    return ($days*-1).' days ago';
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the date into the function.

```
            <?php
                function getTheDay($date)
                {
                    $curr_date=strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
                    $the_date=strtotime($date);
                    $diff=floor(($curr_date-$the_date)/(60*60*24));
                    switch($diff)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            return "Today";
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            return "Yesterday";
                            break;
                        default:
                            return $diff." Days ago";
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Except, this is really looking for more than a difference of 24 hours.  If you are checking a time of yesterday afternoon compared to this morning, it should say yesterday.  The key is to ignore the time parts, and look at just the dates.  If you format each date with `date('Y-m-d')` then it will be comparing midnight on each day and they will either be equal or a multiple of 24 hours apart.  Technically, you then wouldn't need the `floor()` function either.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more polished version of the accepted answer.
It accepts only timestamps and returns a relative date or a formatted date string for everything +/-2 days

```
<?php

/**
 * Relative time
 *
 * date Format http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
 * strftime Format http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php
 * latter can be used with setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
 *
 * @param  timestamp $target
 * @param  timestamp $base   start time, defaults to time()
 * @param  string $format use date('Y') or strftime('%Y') format string
 * @return string
 */
function relative_time($target, $base = NULL, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{

    if(is_null($base)) {
        $base = time();
    }

    $baseDate = new DateTime();
    $targetDate = new DateTime();

    $baseDate->setTimestamp($base);
    $targetDate->setTimestamp($target);

    // don't modify original dates
    $baseDateTemp = clone $baseDate;
    $targetDateTemp = clone $targetDate;

    // normalize times -> reset to midnight that day
    $baseDateTemp = $baseDateTemp->modify('midnight');
    $targetDateTemp = $targetDateTemp->modify('midnight');

    $interval = (int) $baseDateTemp->diff($targetDateTemp)->format('%R%a');

    d($baseDate->format($format));

    switch($interval) {
        case 0:
            return (string) 'today';
        break;

        case -1:
            return (string) 'yesterday';
        break;

        case 1:
            return (string) 'tomorrow';
        break;

        default:
            if(strpos($format,'%') !== false )
            {
                return (string) strftime($format,  $targetDate->getTimestamp());
            }
            return (string) $targetDate->format($format);
        break;

    }
}

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
echo relative_time($weather->time, null, '%A, %#d. %B'); // Montag, 6. August 
echo relative_time($weather->time, null, 'l, j. F'); // Monday, 6. August
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, where I wanted to display keyword "today" or "yesterday" only if date was today and previous day otherwise display date in d-M-Y format

```
<?php
function findDayDiff($date){
   $param_date=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date);
   $response  = $param_date;
   if($param_date==date('d-m-Y',strtotime("now"))){
       $response = 'Today';
   }else if($param_date==date('d-m-Y',strtotime("-1 days"))){
       $response = 'Yesterday'; 
   }
   return $response;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_when($date) {

    $current = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i'));

    $date_diff = $date - $current;
    $difference = round($date_diff/(60*60*24));

    if($difference >= 0) {
            return 'Today';
    } else if($difference == -1) {
            return 'Yesterday';
    } else if($difference == -2 || $difference == -3  || $difference == -4 || $difference == -5) {
            return date('l', $date);
    } else {
            return ('on ' . date('jS/m/y', $date));
    }

}

get_when(date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($your_targeted_date)));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.