# Laravel carbon get today string

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

How I can get string `"today, 12:26"` with **Carbon** in Laravel?

I have date: `"2017-12-17 12:26"`, How can I get these formats?

1) Today, 12:26,
2) 1 hour ago
3) 1 min ago
3) 1 sec ago
4) Yesterday, 12.26
5) 17 december, 12:26

Comment: t should not be that difficult to find this out yourself.

Comment: Many question available with strtotime, you can change strtotime to carbon and use  as you want , [1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622370/php-how-to-check-if-a-date-is-today-yesterday-or-tomorrow), [2nd](https://www.geekshangout.com/php-relative-date-function-today-yesterday-2-days-ago-in-3-days-etc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [diffForHumans method](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff) in Carbon. For example:

```
Carbon::now()->subDays(1)->diffForHumans()
//1 day ago

Carbon::now()->diffForHumans()
//1 second ago

Carbon::now()->subDays(25)->diffForHumans();
// 3 weeks ago
```

**Edit:**

The fact that you are using Laravel, note that you can call **diffForHumans** like this too:

> $user->created_at->diffForHumans();

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar thing in **Carbon**, the `->diffForHumans();` method. Example:

```
echo Carbon::now()->subDays(1)->diffForHumans();
```

Produces:

> 1 day ago

You can always refer to **Carbon** documentation it is very well-documented. [Carbon Documentation.](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)